x86 ASM code not printing the desired number output, only prints the messages
I am trying to find the smallest and largest number given three numbers.
This is my code currently:
    section .text
       global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc
    
    _start:                   ;tell linker entry point
       mov   ecx, [num1]
       mov   ebx, ecx         ; initialize ebx with num1 (smallest so far)
       cmp   ecx, [num2]
       jl    check_third_num  ; jump if num1 < num2
       mov   ecx, [num2]
       mov   ebx, ecx         ; update ebx if num2 is smaller
       
    check_third_num:
       cmp   ecx, [num3]
       jl    update_smallest  ; jump if num2/num1 < num3
       mov   ecx, [num3]
       
    update_smallest:
       mov   [smallest], ecx  ; store the smallest number found
    
       mov   ecx, [num1]
       cmp   ecx, [num2]
       jg    check_largest    ; jump if num1 > num2
       mov   ecx, [num2]
       
    check_largest:
       cmp   ecx, [num3]
       jg    print_result     ; jump if num2/num1 > num3
       mov   ecx, [num3]
    
    print_result:
       mov   [largest], ecx   ; store the largest number found
       
       ; Print the largest number
       mov   ecx, msg_largest
       mov   edx, len_largest
       mov   eax, 4            ; system call number (sys_write)
       mov   ebx, 1            ; file descriptor (stdout)
       int   0x80              ; call kernel
    
       ; Print the smallest number
       mov   ecx, msg_smallest
       mov   edx, len_smallest
       mov   eax, 4            ; system call number (sys_write)
       mov   ebx, 1            ; file descriptor (stdout)
       int   0x80              ; call kernel
    
       mov   eax, 1
       int   80h               ; exit
    
    section .data
       msg_largest db "The largest digit is: ", 0xA, 0xD 
       len_largest equ $ - msg_largest
       msg_smallest db "The smallest digit is: ", 0xA, 0xD 
       len_smallest equ $ - msg_smallest
       num1 dd '47'
       num2 dd '22'
       num3 dd '31'
     
    section .bss
       largest resb 2
       smallest resb 2


I am confused what seems to be the problem. Is it on the update_smallest code, or with the way I declared the things on section .data? I tried tweaking it to convert it first to ASCII, but it kinda confused me, so I tried to just follow what I had in a pdf file I had. I only tried mimicking the structure of it, but now that I added the algorithm to find the smallest number, the code is not printing the smallest and lowest number. This is what I was trying to tweak:
    section .text
       global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc
    
    _start:                   ;tell linker entry point
       mov   ecx, [num1]
       mov   ebx, ecx         ; initialize ebx with num1 (smallest so far)
       cmp   ecx, [num2]
       jl    check_third_num  ; jump if num1 < num2
       mov   ecx, [num2]
       mov   ebx, ecx         ; update ebx if num2 is smaller
       
    check_third_num:
       cmp   ecx, [num3]
       jl    update_smallest  ; jump if num2/num1 < num3
       mov   ecx, [num3]
       
    update_smallest:
       mov   [smallest], ecx  ; store the smallest number found
    
       mov   ecx, [num1]
       cmp   ecx, [num2]
       jg    check_largest    ; jump if num1 > num2
       mov   ecx, [num2]
       
    check_largest:
       cmp   ecx, [num3]
       jg    print_result     ; jump if num2/num1 > num3
       mov   ecx, [num3]
    
    print_result:
       mov   [largest], ecx   ; store the largest number found
       
       ; Print the largest number
       mov   ecx, msg_largest
       mov   edx, len_largest
       mov   eax, 4            ; system call number (sys_write)
       mov   ebx, 1            ; file descriptor (stdout)
       int   0x80              ; call kernel
    
       ; Print the smallest number
       mov   ecx, msg_smallest
       mov   edx, len_smallest
       mov   eax, 4            ; system call number (sys_write)
       mov   ebx, 1            ; file descriptor (stdout)
       int   0x80              ; call kernel
    
       mov   eax, 1
       int   80h               ; exit
    
    section .data
       msg_largest db "The largest digit is: ", 0xA, 0xD 
       len_largest equ $ - msg_largest
       msg_smallest db "The smallest digit is: ", 0xA, 0xD 
       len_smallest equ $ - msg_smallest
       num1 dd '47'
       num2 dd '22'
       num3 dd '31'
     
    section .bss
       largest resb 2
       smallest resb 2


What seems to be the problem in my first code?

Where do you think you print the numbers? I can only see code to print messages ... PS: the resb 2 should be resb 4.


Considering the source code comments you seem to not have understood the following:
The directives db, dd and the like store data in the ascending textual order into memory.
Later data appear at higher addresses.
This means num1 is stored like this:



memory address
memory contents
comment




num1 + 0
0x34
'4'


num1 + 1
0x37
'7'


num1 + 2
0x00
NUL‑padding to occupy a dword.


num1 + 3
0x00
〃



Now when you load a dword with mov from num1, the least significant byte of the ecx register maps to the byte at the smallest memory address (and vice versa).
That means when you compare dd '47' with dd '31' you actually compare the numbers 0x00003734 and 0x00003133.
This scheme is called little Endian.

As an intermediate step, I suggest you make three sys_write system calls.
One for the message prefix, one for the actual number string, and one for the trailing newline.

If that works as expected (= right result), you can increase complexity:
You can reserve some space like this
section .data
msg_largest:
    db 'The largest number is: '
msg_largest_num:
    db '  '
    db 0x0A
len_largest equ $ - msg_largest

and put “the largest” number string at msg_largest_num.
Ensure you overwrite only the two blank bytes.

The character sequence LF+CR (0x0A, 0x0D) is highly unusual:
The travel time for the carriage returning to the left‑hand margin takes more time than the line feed advance, therefore it is and always has been CR+LF, the other way round.
However, apparently you program for a 32‑bit Linux or compatible ABI.
In UNIX‑like environments just a plain LF is sufficient, see “Newline” on Wikipedia for more information.


